# jQuery Ajax / .each callback not returning values

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have this script, so when I click on the button I have to get the values, but is returning me null and 0 values:

SCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
        $("#update_totais").live('click', function(){
            var url="check_totals.php?id_rasc=1";
            $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                $.each(data.totais, function(i,values){
                    total_iliquido = values.total_iliquido;
                    descontos = values.descontos;
                    iva = values.iva;
                    total = values.total2;
            alert(total);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

JSON RETURN:

```
{"totais":[{"total_iliquido":"1500.00","descontos":"0.00","iva":345,"total2":1845}]}
```

I guess is everything right, why is giving me NULL and 0 values?

Comment: what if you use console.log instead of alert? Alert isn't helpful for potentially nested objects. Also, try console.logging data itself, before entering the $.each cycle.

Comment: console: Empty string passed to getElementById().

Comment: that's the output of console.log(data) ?

Comment: this is firefox console errors & warnings

Comment: Ok, but that error might be related to another cause. Please insert ```console.log(data)``` before the ```$.each``` and see what the console shows as data contents.

Comment: 0: Object
descontos: null
iva: 0
total_iliquido: null
totall: 0

Comment: its giving me the same results as alert

Comment: You see, something's not right on data, because it should be ```0: Object descontos: "0.00", iva: 345, total2: 1845, total_iliquido: 1500.00"``` Are you sure about the outcome of url?

Comment: outcome is right, i opened in another page and is showing

Answer (score 0):

You're not going deep enough in order to access the value you need an index and a key:

```
var totais = {"totais":[{"total_iliquido":"1500.00","descontos":"0.00","iva":345,"total2":1845}]};
totais['totais'][0]['iva'] -> 345
```

So try this:

```
var index = 0;
$.each(totais, function(i,values){  
    total_iliquido = values[index]['total_iliquido'];
    descontos = values[index]['descontos'];
    iva = values[index]['iva'];
    total = values[index]['total2'];
    console.log(values[index]['total2']);
  index++;
});
```

The variable i in the function contains the name of the object not the index of the memebers.

Comment: That would defy the purpose of using the ```$.each``` operator. Remember he's already iterating on the ```totais``` array instead of the whole ```data``` object

Comment: Yes within the data object there is the toais object he is iterating over, when I checked the values of i and values it returned toais and the object members respectively. Because the object memeber is an array he needs an index to access it. **THEN** he can get the data within, really this is a formatting issue. Try to access the data within totais via your web console, you have to to go pretty deep to get it.